# EF Core 2.2 Scaffold DbContext and adding Indetity

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core

If I use code first and a context class inherited from `IdentiyDbContext` 
then with `context.Database.EnsureCreated()` EF creates the db and identity tables (AspNetUsers, etc...).

But if I scaffold db context from existing db and then inherit the generated context class from `IdentityDbContext`, at first database access I always have the exception:

> "The entity type 'IdentityUserLogin' requires a primary key to be defined."

And the identity tables aren't created.

How can I add identity tables to existing and scaffolded database?

Thank you

Comment: You want `builder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin<string>>().HasKey(e => e.UserId);` and then `builder.Entity<IdentityUserToken<string>>().HasKey(e => e.UserId);`

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto adding that code simply throws errors for the rest of the models as well

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it was a bug or by design, but the generated dbcontext by scaffolding seems to have a line of code missing. If you check your `OnModelCreating` function in the generated dbcontext, there is no call to the base function. You need to add the following line within the function.

```
base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
```

I added this line at the end and the migrations seem fine. The primary keys seem to be set up using fluent api which would need the base function being called.

**Update**

created an issue and confirmed that this is by design: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/14111

Answer (score 0):

The only way that I found is to generate a new database in codefirst way (starting with context inherited from IdentityContext). At this point I have a database with identity/membership tables. Then I generated a script to create these tables, and applied the script on the existing db.
A.

Comment: did you try the function I mentioned? I was able to replicate your same error and that line fixed the error

Comment: yes, I already had this method on the top of function, I move it at the end, and I have same error message. thank you

Comment: after adding the function how did you test it? the function sets the fluent api. it will need remove and add migrations again

Comment: If I start a new project I don't have migrations yet.After create scaffolded context I inherit the context from IdentityDbContext and if i try to do add-migration <name>  I have the error:

System.InvalidOperationException: The entity type 'IdentityUserLogin<string>' requires a primary key to be defined.